# How do I prevent a javascript function from rendering before another function rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Theoretically speaking let's say I have 3 javascript (jquery) functions that create visual effects.  If I want one of them to render after the first two have been rendered, how can I do this?

Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(function() {
 var transition = 'slow';
 var target1 = $('#somediv');
 var target2 = $('#second_div');
 var target3 = $('#third_div');
 target1.delay(5000).fadeIn();
 target2.delay(target2Time).fadeIn();
 target3.delay(target3Time).fadeIn();
 }); 
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $.fn.teletype = function(opts){
 var $this = this,
    defaults = {
        animDelay: 50
    },
    settings = $.extend(defaults, opts);

 $.each(settings.text, function(i, letter){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $this.html($this.html() + letter);
    }, settings.animDelay * i);
 });
 };

 $(function(){
 $('#second_div').teletype({
    animDelay: 200,
    text: 'Hello, this is your classmate!'
 });
 });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
 <div id="somediv">Some Content</div>
 <div id="second_div"></div>
 <div id="third_div">Some third content</div>
```

Comment: post some code, otherwise it's not possbile to reliably answer your question.

Comment: Use callbacks from each function?

Comment: Which jQuery function do you use?

Comment: Let me post the code.  GIve me a few mins.

Comment: OK everyone.  I posted the code.  Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've made this demo. It demonstrates how to make one animation wait for two other animations to finish:

```
var anim1 = $( '#elem1' ).animate({ width: 200 }, 3000 );
var anim2 = $( '#elem2' ).animate({ width: 200 }, 2000 );

$.when( anim1, anim2 ).done(function () {
   $( '#elem3' ).animate({ width: 200 }, 1000 );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/m67Ua/

---

You can apply the same technique for your fading requirements:

```
var fade1 = $( '#img1' ).fadeIn( 3000 );
var fade2 = $( '#img2' ).fadeIn( 2000 );

$.when( fade1, fade2 ).done(function () {
   $( '#img3' ).fadeIn( 1000 );
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/m67Ua/1/

Comment: Thanks Sime.  I get the idea behind the $.when but in my case i want target 1 and target 2 to load first as target 2 is beign used in another script to render a special effect.  After that I want the target 3,4,5,6 etc to load.

Comment: @KPO What do you mean by load? How do you load those targets? Do you mean fade-in?

Comment: Yes, sorry! i mean the fade-in.

Comment: @KPO It works for fading just the same. See my updated answer.

Comment: Great.  But did you get a chance to see the second function i have? the teleType and animDelay one.  I need that to work with this function too..

Comment: @KPO From what I see, the `teletype()` method does not wait for the fade-in to execute on target 2, correct? (Meaning that it starts writing letters while the element is still hidden.)

Comment: Yes.  So i want the writing to be visible as it's happening rather than beginning while it's still hidden.

Comment: @KPO You want teletype to wait for fade-in to complete, correct?

Comment: Yes, so once the target 1 is loaded.  I want then the teletype to start writing so that it's visible.  Once the writing is complete, i want it to render the next target.

Comment: @KPO Is teletype invoked on all targets?

Comment: @KPO I have an idea, but I'd rather not provide it in my answer as I'm not sure how solid it is. The idea is to use `.queue()` to make sure that the code inside `teletype` waits for the fade-in to finish. Then, once teletype writes the last letter, you could trigger a custom event, e.g. `$(document).trigger('stage1Completed');`, and then bind a handler for that event - `$(document).on('stage1Completed', function () { .. });` which would then initialize the other targets.

Comment: Thanks! let me take a look at your suggestion and work on it.  I am new to javascript only 2-3 months experience but will try to make sense of it! thanks!

Comment: @KPO Your first source should be the jQuery documentation. The `.queue()` method is documented [here](http://api.jquery.com/queue/). Queuing is one of the lesser known parts of jQuery, so there should be tutorials out there. Regarding custom events, it's not actually a separate feature. You have to understand how event handlers are bound, and triggered. Then, you just come up with your own event type names.

Answer (score 2):

Just as improvement, you can pass an array of animations

```
 var array = new Array();
 array.push( $( '#img1' ).fadeIn( 3000 ));
 array.push( $( '#img2' ).fadeIn( 2000 ));
```

And then the trick is change from array to list arguments as expected by jquery, using the **apply** method

```
$.when.apply(this, array ).done(function () {
    $( '#img3' ).fadeIn( 1000 );
});
```

Live demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/m67Ua/2/

Answer (score 0):

i needed the callbacks and the done, so check this out:

```
$.when(
    $('#container .item')
        .animate({"opacity": "0"}, 1000, 
            function onCallbackForEach () {
                console.log('callback on element called');
            })
).done( function onFinally () {
    console.log('done called');
});
```

which gives me access to handle the elements each after their animation (e.g. replace an old one with them), and aditionally having a single callback to do work after all of the animations have finished...